# How to use the elevator?

Tags: the-expendabros

The mission after the first boss includes one of those elevators. I wonder how to use them. There are two arrows (up/down). Going to these direction buttons has no effect. How do I trigger them when playing WASD or ArrowKeys? (With XBox360 controller it's the Y key)
[image: related picture]

Comment: You may have to call maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press c, just figured it out myself

Comment: Ok: `C` is when playing with coursor keys, when playing with WASD however it's `U`